# Give dynamic runnables to my JPanel class using its own Graphics object?

Tags: java, swing, runnable

All right, just hear me out. I currently have a class similar to the one below:

```
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponents(g);
       g.setColor(Color.RED);
       g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

But obviously this wouldn't be very useful, since the only thing it can do is make a `fillRect`. Now what I want to do is to have the parent JFrame to be able to pass custom instructions to one of its panes, so every instance of `GraphicsPanel` would be able to do something different. I want to be able to keep adding instructions as runnables to the object. I have a general design in mind:

```
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5890041512607678296L;
private java.util.List<Runnable> graphics = new ArrayList<Runnable>();

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);

    for (Runnable r: graphics) {
        r.run();
    }
}

public void addGraphics(Runnable r) {
    graphics.add(r);
}

public void clearGraphics() {
    graphics.clear();
}
}
```

And something like this would be called in the parent frame's code:

```
graphicspane.addGraphics(() -> {
    g.fillOval(200, 200, 200, 200);
});

//Later, in a button ActionListener or some other event...
graphicspane.addGraphics(() -> {
    g.fillArc(200, 200, 200, 200, 13, 16);
});

//Also later, dynamically called by parent JFrame...
graphicspane.clearGraphics();
```

As you can see, all I really want is to be able to give dynamic instructions to the GraphicsPanel. **Here is the problem, however:** When I create the runnables in the parent JFrame, for obvious reasons, I cannot give instructions using the graphics object of the JPanel, because I can't access the local Graphics argument `g` in the scope of the JFrame.

I'm pretty sure what I want is a fairly simple kind of thing to do, yet there seems to be no obvious path from here. If you have a suggestion that involves scrapping my current design for something simpler, please share it. I tend to reinvent the wheel at times and perhaps I'm going about this completely wrong. Thanks!

Comment: instead of Runnable, create an own interface with one method that accepts a Graphics or just use `Consumer<Graphihcs>` (also consider camickr answer)

Comment: Rather then trying to access the `Graphics` context, instead, pass "commands" to the component which it can then use to generate the result - I'd start by looking at the `Shape`s API for inspiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I currently have a class similar to the one below:

That is not how you do custom painting.

You should:

1. be overriding `paintComponent(...)` - not paint()
2. then invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` - not super.paintComponent().

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

> pass custom instructions to one of its panes, so every instance of GraphicsPanel would be able to do something different. I want to be able to keep adding instructions as runnables to the object.

You don't add Runnable objects to do painting. Swing determines when paiting is done, so the paintComponent() method simply paints the current state of your panel.

So to change the state of your panel you can keep an ArrayList of Objects you want to paint. You create a method to add objects to paint to the ArrayList. Then in the paintComponent() method you iterate through the ArrayList to paint each object.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of this approach.

In your case because you want to paint different objects you would want to add `Shape` objects to the ArrayList. The `Shape` interface supports arcs, rectangles, ovals etc.